# CSS Grid vertical expand an element without affecting the other elements in Row

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid

I've been using CSS grids to style a variable amount of cards. Each card has an accordion that can be toggled to show more information. Upon toggle it will expand the card, and subsequently expand the card in the row to the same height. It there any way to allow the card to expand only vertically, without affecting the row, and the height of the other card in the row? Take a look at these photos to get a better idea. My intuition is that maybe I should shift away from CSS grids, but I wanted to see if it was possible:

Here is my CSS for the grids:

```css
.dynamicprofgrid {
  width: 100%;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: .4fr 1fr;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px
  
}


.profdatagrid {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  margin: 20px
}
```

[image: Before Expanding accordion]
[![After Expanding accordion]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZAM2.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZAM2.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Please create a runnable snippet that shows the problem. Your HTML structure is important here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You **could** specify that the element expands to **two** rows `grid-row: span 2` on expansion. This will push the next row down while retaining the height of the row you are in.